# AOSP Oreo - Camera Permission for priv-app App

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-source

In a custom android Oreo AOSP, is possible grant camera permission for my app in priv-app folder?

I know that is a dangerous permission and should be granted in runtime, but there is any other option that not require the user interaction if the app is in system/priv-app?

I saw that there is a whitelist in /etc/permissions, https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-whitelist, but I think that is no for dangerous permissions, like camera.

Answer (score 1):

You can grant dangerous permission for private application in `/system/priv-app`:

Create the default permission file `default-permission-sample.xml`. You need to replace package name by your app's package name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<exceptions>
    <exception package="com.your.camera">
        <permission name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    </exception>
</exceptions>
```

Then config makefile to copy `default-permission-sample.xml` into `/system/etc/default-permissions/` directory.

DONE.

Comment: Didn't know about this. @MapX, nevermind my answer, go with this :)

Comment: Hi @TuanPM, thanks for the reply! I have to do that before compile the system image, right?
Because I added the **default-permission-sample.xml** in the system image that I already have and didn't work.

Comment: @MapX yes. You need to do that before compile the system image because as i know the Android only grant default permissions on the first booting time.

Comment: @TuanPM You can delete this file : /data/system/users/0/runtime-permissions.xml  and reboot. Android will redo the granting proces, taking into account yout newly pushed file

Comment: @RickSanchez I already tried with the way you mentioned but it didn't work for me. I don't know why. Anyway your way is one option to try.

Comment: I tried that yesterday and it did work. Granted I was trying on Android 9, so it could be because of changes between them

Answer (score 0):

You can grant default runtime permissions to a package by modifying [frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/permission/DefaultPermissionGrantPolicy.java](http://frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/permission/DefaultPermissionGrantPolicy.java)

The relevant method here would be:

```
private void grantDefaultSystemHandlerPermissions(PackageManagerWrapper pm, int userId)
```

For example, [this](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/permission/DefaultPermissionGrantPolicy.java;l=832) is how STORAGE permissions are granted to *"com.android.sharedstoragebackup"* :

```
// There is no real "marker" interface to identify the shared storage backup, it is
// hardcoded in BackupManagerService.SHARED_BACKUP_AGENT_PACKAGE.
grantSystemFixedPermissionsToSystemPackage(pm, "com.android.sharedstoragebackup", userId,
                STORAGE_PERMISSIONS);
```